# How to plot a matematical equation on Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm try to plot a graph on python using matplotlib, but i can't to get a expected result.

Equation 1: `1/2 * (w1 + w2) + 1/2 * np.sqrt(4*(g)**2 + (w2-w1)**2)`

Equation 2: `1/2 * (w1 + w2) - 1/2 * np.sqrt(4*(g)**2 + (w2-w1)**2)`

My python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def W_p(w1,w2,g):
   return 1/2 * (w1 + w2) + 1/2 * np.sqrt(4*(g)**2 + (w2-w1)**2)

def W_m(w1,w2,g):
    return 1/2 * (w1 + w2) - 1/2 * np.sqrt(4*(g)**2 + (w2-w1)**2)

w1 = np.linspace(-10,10,1)
w2 = np.linspace(0.9,1.10,0.1)
g = 1

plt.plot(W_p(w1,w2,g), 'r', W_m(w1,w2,g), 'b')

plt.show()
```

The generatad graph should look like the graph on the image below:

[image]

Comment: What result do you get instead?

Comment: where is your result ?

Answer (score 14):

> **numpy.linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False,
> dtype=None)**
>
> Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
>
> Returns num evenly spaced samples, calculated over the interval
> [start, stop].
>
> The endpoint of the interval can optionally be excluded.
>
> Parameters:
>
> start : scalar The starting value of the sequence.
>
> stop :
> scalar The end value of the sequence, unless endpoint is set to False.
> In that case, the sequence consists of all but the last of num + 1
> evenly spaced samples, so that stop is excluded. Note that the step
> size changes when endpoint is False.
>
> num : int, optional **Number of samples to generate**. Default is 50. Must be non-negative.
>
> **....**

Must be change

```
w1 = np.linspace(-10,10,1)
w2 = np.linspace(0.9,1.1,0.1)
```

to

```
w1 = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
w2 = np.linspace(0.9,1.1,100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of `np.linspace()` is the *number of points*. It should not be either 1 or 0.1. Try 100.